# Create character vector of filenames in numeric sequence with leading zeroes

Tags: r

I need to generate 100 file names.

How would you generate the corresponding character vector `files` in R containing 100 file names:  `plot01.png, plot02.png, plot03.png, ..., plot99.png, plot100.png`? Notice that the numbers of the first 9 files start with 0.

The obvious but very ineffective solution is to write a vector with 100 file names. I'm trying to figure out a more effective way to create this character vector.

Comment: `paste(formatC(1:100, flag = "0", width = 3), "png", sep = ".")`

Comment: Different scenario but same need to read files with the numbers 001-100: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216454/how-to-read-multiple-csv-files-by-creating-function

Comment: Or just `sprintf("%02d.png", 1:100)` ?

Comment: @SamFirke - even better :-) Post that as an answer, though I think they want `%02d`

Comment: If you're getting into 3 digits, are you sure you want `plot01` not `plot001`?

Comment: I've added the "plot" prefix to my answer, I'd missed that before.  BTW this question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348910/r-project-filepath-from-concatenation, though not an exact duplicate (there's more going on in that question).

Answer (score 5):

A concise option is `paste0("plot", sprintf("%02d.png", 1:100))`:

```
  [1] "plot01.png"  "plot02.png"  "plot03.png"  "plot04.png" ...
```

Another approach that is more characters to write, but maybe easier to follow, is string padding with `str_pad` from the stringr package:

```
library(stringr)
paste0("plot", str_pad(1:100, width = 2, side = "left", pad = 0), ".png")
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine `paste` and `formatC`:

```
paste(formatC(1:100, flag = "0", width = 2), "png", sep = ".")
#  [1] "01.png"  "02.png"  "03.png"  "04.png"  "05.png"  "06.png"  "07.png" ...
```

Comment: I think OP wants `width=2`